# Can I update an older git commit message without rebasing

Tags: git

I made a commit to a branch with a typo in the commit message (misspelling the Jira issue key).  Then I merged in another branch, with many conflicts, a long, drawn-out, arduous process I am not eager to redo.  Our git repository is set up to reject any push which contains commits that do not have a valid Jira issue key in them, so I need to fix this commit before I can push.

So I need to update the commit message, but I would really really like to it without using interactive rebase.  I can use git cat-file on the commit to see the commit message I want to fix, but I haven't been able to find anything in the git documentation that seems to do the opposite, to update a message.  The file in the .git/objects subfolder is clearly encrypted/compressed in some way, so I can't edit it directly.

Is it in principle possible to edit the commit message directly?  Would it break things, e.g. cause the commit hash to need to be different?  (Is that why they're called "hashes"?)

Failing that, is there an easier way to do an actual rebase and redo the merge without having to pick and choose every conflict resolution?  (I suppose I could just make a copy of the file tree in a post-merge state and then paste them back in...?)

Comment: So I checked out the repo just after the merge commit, copied that to another folder, and then did the interactive rebase, preserving merges.  It was tedious, but slightly less ugly than resolving all those conflicts again manually (particularly since I had four commits after that that would probably have had their own conflicts if I hadn't reproduced all of my original conflict resolution choices).  Clearly I need to inspect my commit messages for typos before doing any merges.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this situation. I made a typo in the summary line of one of my commits that makes said summary almost useless, but now it's been built upon, merged, even pushed to a remote. *Of course, I'm the only one interacting with that remote, so I could **in theory** rebase and just make a lot of work for myself to clean up "later"*… but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to NONDISRUPTIVELY fix such mistakes. The only thing I can think is to revert and then redo the offending commit. The revert will show in various tools and make the typo seem less relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Interactive rebase can be used in a way that preserves merge commits. If you just specify "reword" on that one commit all the rest of your history will remain the same if you have "pick" next to them. This wouldn't affect your merge.

Comment: Alas, this does not turn out to be the case.  When I try to do an interactive rebase starting at the commit before my typo (which is the commit before the merge), then it quickly runs into the merge commit and prompts me to fix the conflicts.  As a matter of fact, it seems like it might be trying to get to resolve the conflicts for each of the commits in the branch I merged in, which seems even  less helpful.

Comment: Hah, I forgot the "preserve merges" option.  (I'm using Git Extensions for this because I have never taken to command-line git, except in extreme cases.)  Still, it does present me with the merge and ask me to resolve all those conflicts all over again.

Comment: That's not a problem though because since you've already committed the conflict resolutions, you can reapply the same resolution by checking out the files from those conflict-resolved commits during the interactive rebase.